# Olympic Squat Mobility

Tags: squats, flexibility, olympic-weightlifting, mobility

How can I achieve a similar flexibilty like [this](https://youtu.be/AvrzgKsRnJ0) (not talking about the weight, just empty bar for example)? I like his squatting style alot and would like to be able to get into the same bottom position.

What are the most important stretches ([here](http://www.allthingsgym.com/hip-and-ankle-stretches-for-olympic-weightlifting/) I found a good list)?

How can I pin-point which muscles/ areas are my worst? I am searching for mobilty tests for:

- Hip
- Ankles
- Hamstrings

Comment: Isn't the article that you linked his proposed stretching routine?

Comment: @SeanDuggan corrected that! No I am searching for tests to know what is wrong!

Comment: @progressive_overload - Do this - Sit on a bench that is tall enough your feet don't touch the floor (Think like a massage table or doctors exam table, etc). Scoot back until the backs of your knees are at the edge of the bench, and let your feet hang free. Note which way your toes point, and mimic that in your squat position. For example, my left foot points towards 11 on a clock rather than straight ahead, and my right somewhere around 2. I do best when squatting/leg press in that position.

Comment: Search for "Elloitt Hulse" on youtube, he has some good hip and ankle flexing videos in which he explains how to do proper stretching before squatting. He has good videos about working out and stretching in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the squat without shoes and if you cant get down or are falling backwards you might have to work on flexibility of the achilles tendon.

For general squating flexibility gobblet-squats are great.
http://breakingmuscle.com/kettlebells/how-to-do-the-perfect-goblet-squat

For working on the achilles flexibility you should do some of these exercises:
http://www.mikereinold.com/2013/03/ankle-mobility-exercises-to-improve-dorsiflexion.html

Comment: thank you for your tips! i guess that it will take weeks or months to see real  progress in my flexibility.:(

Answer (score 0):

Squats w/o shoes gives better ankle flexibility. 
To go lower, most of my problems came form hips. Here is set of exercises to start:
http://breakingmuscle.com/mobility-recovery/6-mobility-exercises-for-an-a-to-grass-squat

Perhaps there are better pictures, better explanation. But as a set - good one. I've tried on youtube, but all are joga... Looks great, but IMVHO too great.

Be warned. Making your joins more mobile, drops power. That is somehow temporal, but please be sure to go down with load after aggressive stretching. And that has to be aggressive, since you are attacking not muscles, but collagen, fascias. Number two from that set was killer to me

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to keep in mind he is wearing Adidas lifting shoes, these have a raised heel (0,75 inch) which will give a tremendous advantage in mobility.

As for mobility exercises just roll everything out with either a foam roll or a lacrosse ball. That works for me.

Comment: I'm already wearing those but cannot even remotely get into such a good position :(

Comment: Try OmarIsuf on youtube he has got some great vids on mobility. You could also generally search youtube for mobility exercises. You will probably mostly be looking for hip and ankle mobility (also called ankle or hip dorsiflexion).

Comment: http://www.alexrothwell.com/articles/your-complete-guide-to-mobility-for-olympic-weightlifting I just found this link on mobility for the olympic lifts, the mobility the guy in the vid has. Hope this helps. I haven't checked the link myself though, was just browsing fitness.SE